# Shortest OpenGL geometry shader example that will run on Linux?

Tags: linux, opengl, shader

I am looking for a a short OpenGL geometry shader example that will run on Linux, preferably with as few dependencies as possible. Basically I want to use that program as a test to see if geometry shaders are supported at all on the system it's currently running on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `glxinfo` (in the package `mesa-utils` on Ubuntu/Debian) and check the extension list (`GL_EXT/ARB_geometry_shader4`) or OpenGL version (>= 3.2) for geometry shader support.

Extension example:

```
user@machine:~$ glxinfo | grep "GL_EXT_framebuffer_object"
GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object,
```

Version example:

```
user@machine:~$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.10.2
```